# How to store working days and check if a date matches that day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres and trying to understand how to store and also query against working days.

I have an attribute on my `users` table called  `working_days` which is an int array.

If a person only works on Monday and Wednesday, then I will store `[0, 2]`

If I want to know which users are available to work "today" which happens to be a Tuesday, I want to find users who have `working_hours` of `[1]`.

How can I get the day from the date, and is there some better way to do this?

Comment: `extract(dow from current_date)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE working_days &&
      ARRAY[
         CAST((extract(dow FROM current_timestamp) + 1) % 7
               AS integer
         )
      ];
```

This uses the "array overlaps" operator `&&` with a one-element array constructed from the current week day.

A GIN index on `working_days` can speed up the query.